# html5 WebSocket

Tags: html, websocket

I already have a server with port and want to write a web app to get the information form the port. Will this be possible with WebPorts?

The Client doesn't even need to talk back to the server, which is the whole point of websockets I would imagine, but since I already have the ports setup, I might be easier and cleaner to just connect and get the info without having to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets are **not** intended as clear TCP channels over which other existing protocols can be implemented.

WebSockets are designed to allow messages to be sent between a client and server, where an event is raised each time a message is received.

Hence a WebSocket client cannot simply connect to an existing TCP server - that server also has to speak the WebSocket protocol.

You could of course write a WebSocket-based server that does nothing but act as a *proxy* to existing network services.

Comment: Thank you exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: I agree that you need a WebSocket server or gateway of some sort. However, you can definitely extend the reach of business protocols on top of WebSockets all the way to the browser. Examples for existing protocols and APIs over WebSockets include [XMPP](http://kaazing.com/products/xmpp-edition), [JMS](http://kaazing.com/products/jms-edition), [AMQP](http://kaazing.com/products/amqp-edition).

Comment: @PeterMoskovits sure, you can use a WebSocket gateway to act as a _proxy_ between a web app and an existing socket socket.

Comment: Here's the updated link to the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway: http://kaazing.com/download/

Comment: The claim in the first sentence is not correct. There are stream APIs available for both client and server, not just event-based ones. However it certainly is a protocol of its own with its own framing, so you need a WebSocket implemetation at both ends.

Comment: @EJP I think you're misreading what I've written.   What I was trying to say (but perhaps failed) is that you can't for example write something like an IRC client using WebSockets and expect it to speak directly to a native IRC server.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) which is a WebSocket to plain TCP socket bridge/proxy. It also allows sending and receiving of binary data with the older version of the WebSocket protocol which hadn't yet added direct binary data support.

Disclaimer: I created websockify.

Comment: Would that be a 'claimer' instead? ;)